# How to order list items by simple hierarchy in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a list of link (error message) pointing to a control into a page. 
The order of links is not the same as the control there pointing to. 
I want to reorder my links.

sample :

```js
$(function() {
   //reorder errorList,
   // getOrder(idcontrol){???}
});
```

```css
input, select,a {
  display:table;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>The original list or errors.</h3>
<div id="errorList">
        <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
        <a data-idcontrol="list3">error list3</a>
        <a data-idcontrol="textbox1">error textbox1</a>
        <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
        <a data-idcontrol="list1">error list1</a>
    </div>

<h3>Elements in the page</h3>
    <input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
    <input type="text" id="textbox2"/>
    <select id="list1"><option>item1</option></select>
    <input type="text" id="textbox3"/>
    <select id="list2"><option>item1</option></select>
    <select id="list3"><option>item1</option></select>


<h3>What should be the list of errors after been reordered.</h3>
<div id="errorListShouldBeAfterReorderOnLoad">
         <a data-idcontrol="textbox1">error textbox1</a>
            <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
            <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
            <a data-idcontrol="list1">error list1</a>
            <a data-idcontrol="list3">error list3</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: And where's the jQuery code? `//reorder errorList` won't allow us to see what's happening.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, add the tag

Comment: I dont have the code for reorder, thats what I looking for, or where should I looking for. I dont know how to get the order/hierarchy in the page of my control (by id-control).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort the errors based on the index of the element it belongs to

```
$('#errorList a').sort(function(a,b) {
    var data1  = $(a).data('idcontrol'),
        data2  = $(b).data('idcontrol'),
        index1 = $('#' + data1).index(),
        index2 = $('#' + data2).index();

    return index1 - index2;
}).appendTo('#errorList');
```

Comment: I did it in fiddle and its seems to work. https://jsfiddle.net/6ztqckqa/