# How to order by complex hierarchy in page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I posted a problem ([How to order list items by simple hierarchy in page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40635345/javascript-order-by-simple-hierarchy-in-page)); the answer responded to the question but only because my sample wasn't sufficiently complex.

I need to find the index of an element compared to a very high parent or maybe the entire page. Could be the index in comparison to the entire dom.

The code there not working because index() always returns 0 (if control are not in the same parent)
https://jsfiddle.net/6ztqckqa/3/

```
$(function() {
  //reorder errorList,
  $('#errorList a').sort(function(a, b) {
    var data1 = $(a).data('idcontrol'),
      data2 = $(b).data('idcontrol'),
      index1 = $('#' + data1).index(),
      index2 = $('#' + data2).index();

    return index1 - index2;
  }).appendTo('#errorList');
});
```

HTML:

```
<h3>The original list or errors.</h3>
<div id="errorListOriginal">
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="list3">error list3</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox1">error textbox1</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="list1">error list1</a>
</div>
<h3>The list or errors reordered.</h3>
<div id="errorList">
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="list3">error list3</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox1">error textbox1</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="list1">error list1</a>
</div>

<h3>What should be the list of errors after been reordered.</h3>
<div id="errorListShouldBeAfterReorderOnLoad">
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox1">error textbox1</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="textbox2">error textbox2</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="list1">error list1</a>
    <a data-idcontrol="list3">error list3</a>
</div>

<h3>Elements in the page</h3>
<div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="textbox1" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <input type="text" id="textbox2" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <select id="list1">
                    <option>item1</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" id="textbox3" />
            </div>
            <select id="list2">
                <option>item1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select id="list3">
            <option>item1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to use z-index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is element before or after another element in DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902270/is-element-before-or-after-another-element-in-dom)

Answer (score 0):

At least some of your stack of nested divs should have classes on them indicating their purpose. Elements of the same class should be at the same level in the DOM tree so that you can select them and get their indexes.

Otherwise, apply a class or an ID to the top-level parent and target its children.

The bottom line is that clean, semantic markup is key.

Answer (score 0):

I used brute force base on [Is element before or after another element in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902270/is-element-before-or-after-another-element-in-dom)

here on fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6ztqckqa/5

```
$(function() {
  //reorder errorList,
  $('#errorList a').sort(function(a, b) {
    var data1 = $(a).data('idcontrol'),
      data2 = $(b).data('idcontrol');

            var all = $('input, select');

            var index1 = all.index($("#" + data1));
            var index2 = all.index($("#" + data2));

    return index1 - index2;
  }).appendTo('#errorList');
});
```